# Adding an OR grouping condition to this code

Tags: javascript

```
      {chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'number' &&
        chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage' && (
          <div className="mt-1 remove remove-input-txt-border">
            <Controller
              name="settings.yAxis.aggregation"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) =>
```

I want to make an addition to this code snipet here.

Currently it works when:
yAxis type = number
and
chart type != percentage

I want to change it to work when:

yAxis type = number
and
chart type != percentage

or

yAxis type = formula
and
chart type != percentage

No attempts made so far

Comment: Have you tried using the logical or operator (`||`)?

Answer (score 0):

Your logic can be simplified to this:

(yAxis type = number or yAxis type = formula) and chart type != percentage

The simpler way:

```
      {(chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'number' || chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'formula') &&
        chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage' && (
          <div className="mt-1 remove remove-input-txt-border">
            <Controller
              name="settings.yAxis.aggregation"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) =>
```

The cleaner way:

```
      {['number', 'formula'].includes(chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type) &&
        chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage' && (
          <div className="mt-1 remove remove-input-txt-border">
            <Controller
              name="settings.yAxis.aggregation"
              control={control}
              render={({ field }) =>
```

Answer (score 0):

> No attempts made so far

How could you even not try first before asking for help, * *sighs* *

```
chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'number' && chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage'
```

to

```
(
  (chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'number' && chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage') || 
  (chart?.record?.settings?.yAxis?.type === 'formula ' && chart?.record?.chartType != 'percentage')
)
```

Hope you at least try next time